# Is there a way to change the slider colour in an embedded YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, youtube

Specifically, I'd like to change the progress bar to blue.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#color .. Looks like that's all the control you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't give you the option? I don't like 'don't' <--- A great bit of irony.

P.S. I Answered on this question as it's top on Google Search with this specific question.

I use this to change the colour of the progress bar with simple hands down CSS...

```
.ytp-play-progress {
     color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope! Unfortunately, they just don't let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/08/coming-soon-dark-player-for-embeds.html

You can change the color to white or red. That's all.