# How to change the color of the YouTube player's progress bar

Tags: html, css, youtube

I'm trying to apply the change to a YouTube video that is not embedded.

I have read the information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181582/html-change-color-on-youtube-video) but it seems to be outdated!

I am using the Arc browser and a new feature called Boost whereby one can customize the looks of a web page using custom CSS rules.

Currently, the player's progress bar is light gray and I would like to change it to red using a CSS rule.

[image: YouTube player light gray progress bar]

I explored the HTML code and just don't understand how the color is set and which selector would do the job!

[image]